# VB.net connection string works, then doesn't, then does - why?

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.NET, VS 19  v16.10.4

I have a small application which asks a user to provide database server, database name and then builds a connection string. Then, using a data access layer DLL I've written it runs a check to see if a connection can be made to the database.

The problem is unusual:
If I write the connection string direct to the data access layer into a variable it connects;

If I use a string builder to build the string then pass it to the data access layer it fails;

If I write the connection string into a variable then pass it to the data access layer it fails;

If I use the first step again it works.

```
 With DAL

            MessageBox.Show("Using hard-coded string")
            .ConnectionString = "data source=THEWINELIBRARY\MSSQLSERVER01;initial catalog=TrialDatabase;trusted_connection=true"
            .DoConnectionCheck() 'THIS WORKS


            MessageBox.Show("Using string builder string")
            .ConnectionString = SBConnString.ToString.Trim
            .DoConnectionCheck() 'THIS FAILS

            MessageBox.Show("Using CS string")
            .ConnectionString = CS.Trim
            .DoConnectionCheck() 'THIS FAILS

            MessageBox.Show("Using hard-coded string")
            .ConnectionString = "data source=THEWINELIBRARY\MSSQLSERVER01;initial catalog=TrialDatabase;trusted_connection=true"
            .DoConnectionCheck() 'THIS WORKS

        End With
```

The data access layer does the following in the DoConnectionCheck method:

```
 Public Sub DoConnectionCheck()
            OpenConnection()
            With AppConnection
                If (.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
                    RaiseEvent ConnectionOpened()
                    CloseConnection()
               
                End If
            End With
        End Sub
```

and the OpenConnection method:

```
Private Sub OpenConnection()
        With AppConnection
            'Is the conenction currently closed?
            If (.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
                Try
                    'Set connection string to POS
                    .ConnectionString = ConnectionString
                    'Try opening the connection
                    .Open()

                    'Otherwise raise an event.
                Catch E As Exception
                    RaiseEvent ConnectionFailed()

                End Try

            End If

        End With

    End Sub
```

And the connection string is a simple property:

```
 Public ConnectionString As String
```

So, what I don't understand is why the connection fails with the string builder string and the variable string, but not with the hard-coded string?

If there is any other code you need please let me know, I posted what i think is enough to explain the problem without putting in too much that makes the question unreadable.

here is the code which constructs the connection string from entries in a form:

```
 Dim CS As String = "datasource=" & .TextServer.Text.Trim & ";initial catalog=" & .TextDatabase.Text.Trim & ";trusted_connection=true"

    

SBConnString = New StringBuilder
        With SBConnString
            .Clear()
            .Append("datasource=")
            .Append(Me.TextServer.Text.Trim)
            .Append(";initial catalog=")
            .Append(Me.TextDatabase.Text.Trim)
            .Append(";trusted_connection=true")
        End With
```

When these strings are compared to the hard coded string

```
DAL.ConnectionString = "data source=THEWINELIBRARY\MSSQLSERVER01;initial catalog=TrialDatabase;trusted_connection=true"
```

the function returns a value 1, "The first substring follows the second substring in the sort order." according to the documentation.

As far as I can see, these strings are identical but somewhere an additional character must be getting inserted in the form textbox.

Again, any suggestions gratefully received.

All the best,

Dermot

Comment: Doublecheck the values in those variables: are they *really* identical to the hardcoded values?

Comment: Yes - in two strings I had datasource, NOT data source...
As you've cleared up a silly mistake on my part I'll delete the question tomorrow! Thanks,

Comment: This is a fine example of why you should use a connection string builder to build a connection string. For SQL Server, that would be a `SqlConnectionstringBuilder`. They can't stop you messing up the values, but at least they can stop you messing up the field names.

Comment: Excellent comment - thanks. It's a class I had not come across before so it looks exactly what I wanted in the first place.

Comment: A quick word of caution - if you use the SQLConnectionStringBuilder you have to use .ToLower when passing it - it capitalises words such as data source and that can cause a failure to conenct.

Comment: Connection should be created in the method where they are used so they can be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Mea culpa - I had a very simple mistake which I could not see - in the two strings causing the problem I had datasource rather than date source...